Save Smiley from Form in mariaDB
I would like to save form entries with smileys (from Android) in my DB and of course output them afterwards.
I have an html form [enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]. Using php8 I write the data to my MariaDB 10.11. The database is set to utf8mb4_unicode_ci. Normally I only use utf8mb3_general_ci.
I use: 'mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['comment'])',
but without escape it does not work either.
Unfortunately, Android users like to use the graphic smileys from the Android keyboard. How can I save/convert these in my DB?

The column needs to be CHARACTER SET utf8mb4.

the database character set is just the default for new tables, and the table character set is just the default for new columns; if your table already exists you need to alter the column
